# Elegant way test in python if string contains nothing except 0-9,e,+,-,spaces,tabs

Tags: python

I would like to find the most efficient and simple way to test in python if a string passes the following criteria:

- contains nothing except:

  - digits (the numbers 0-9)
  - decimal points: '.'
  - the letter 'e'
  - the sign '+' or '-'
  - spaces (any number of them)
  - tabs (any number of them)

I can do this easily with nested 'if' loops, etc., but i'm wondering if there's a more convenient way...

For example, I would want the string:

```
0.0009017041601  5.13623e-05   0.00137531   0.00124203
```

to be 'true' and all the following to be 'false':

```
#   File generated at 10:45am Tuesday, July 8th
#   Velocity:  82.568
#   Ambient Pressure:  150000.0

     Time(seconds)      Force_x           Force_y           Force_z
```

Comment: what you tried?? show us ur code

Comment: let's just say it's several nested for / if statements for each criteria. I know it's not the right way to do it :(

Comment: you should try and use the 're' module, which is the python module for regex.
get started with simple examples here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Is that really what you want? Or do you want to parse it into floating-point numbers?

Comment: Are you trying to check whether the string is a number, possibly in scientific notation? There are better ways for doing that.

Comment: @Jenny_Winters they can be in any order???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's trivial for a regex, using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
import re
if re.match(r"[0-9e \t+.-]*$", subject):
     # Match!
```

However, that will (according to the rules) also match `eeeee` or `+-e-+` etc...

If what you actually want to do is check whether a given string is a valid number, you could simply use

```
try:
    num = float(subject)
except ValueError:
    print("Illegal value")
```

This will handle strings like `"+34"` or `"-4e-50"` or `"    3.456e7          "`.

Comment: there is no need of ^ as match matches from starting of string

Comment: @Hackaholic: I know, Python is weird that way, implying one anchor but not the other.

Comment: after looking things over, regexes are definitely the way to go. but, please edit your answer so it says r"[0-9e \t+-.]*$" (i had forgotten about decimal points!)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
if re.match(r"^[0-9\te+ -]+$",x):
     print "yes"
else:
     print "no"
```

You can try this.If there is a match,its a pass else fail.Here x will be your string.

Comment: there is no need of `^` as match matches from starting of string

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use regular expressions just use a test_list and `all` operation :

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> test_list=list(digits)+['+','-',' ','\t','e','.']
>>> all(i in test_list for i in s)
```

Demo:

```
>>> s ='+4534e '
>>> all(i in test_list for i in s)
True
>>> s='+9328a '
>>> all(i in test_list for i in s)
False
>>> s="0.0009017041601 5.13623e-05 0.00137531 0.00124203"
>>> all(i in test_list for i in s)
True
```

Comment: this works, but regexes are definitely the way to go here. thanks @Kasra!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to check whether the string has only required characters is by using the string.translate method.

```
num = "1234e+5"
if num.translate(None, "0123456789e+- \t"
    print "pass"
else:
    print "Wrong character present!!!"
```

You can add any character at the second parameter in the translate method other than that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, running a regular expression check is costly, depending on the expression. Also running a regex check for each valid line (i.e. lines which the value should be "True") *will* be costly, especially because you'll end up parsing each line with a regex and parse the same line again to get the numbers.

You did not say what you wanted to do with the data so I will empirically assume a few things.

First off in a case like this I would make sure the data source is always formatted the same way. Using your example as a template I would then define the following convention:

1. any line, which first non-blank character is a hash sign is ignored
2. any blank line is ignored
3. any line that contains only spaces is ignored

This kind of convention makes parsing much easier since you only need one regular expression to fit rules `1.` to `3.` : `^\s*(#|$)`, i.e. any number of space followed by either a hash sign or an end of line. On the performance side, this expression scans an entire line only when it's comprised of spaces and just spaces, which shall not happen very often. In other cases the expression scans a line and stops at the first non-space character, which means comments will be detected quickly for the scanning will stop as soon as the hash is encountered, at position `0` most of the time.

If you can also enforce the following convention:

- the first non blank line of the remaining lines is the header with column names
- there is no blank lines between samples
- there are no comments in samples

Your code would then do the following:

1. read lines into `line` for as long as `re.match(r'^\s*(#|$)', line)` evaluates to `True`;
2. continue, reading headers from the next line into `line`: `headers = line.split()` and you have headers in a list.

You can use a `namedtuple` for your line layout — which I assume is constant throughout the same data table:

```
class WindSample(namedtuple('WindSample', 'time, force_x, force_y, force_z')):
    def __new__(cls, time, force_x, force_y, force_z):
        return super(WindSample, cls).__new__(
            cls,
            float(time),
            float(force_x),
            float(force_y),
            float(force_z)
        )
```

Parsing valid lines would then consist of the following, for each `line`:

```
try:
    data = WindSample(*line.split())
except ValueError, e:
    print e
```

Variable data would hold something such as:

```
>>> print data
WindSample(time=0.0009017041601, force_x=5.13623e-05, force_y=0.00137531, force_z=0.00124203)
```

The advantage is twofold:

1. you run costly regular expressions only for the smallest set of lines (i.e. blank lines and comments);
2. your code parses floats, raising an exception whenever parsing would yield something invalid.